# vim shows empty block at end of each line

Tags: vim, vi

While editing a file in Vim, I tried to do a global search and replace, but I accidentally hit enter after typing this:

```
:g/$/x
```

Now Vim is in a funny state where an empty blue box appears at the end of each line, not only in the file I was editing, but in EVERY file I open!  I've logged out and back in, but the strange state persists.  What happened, and how can I get Vim back to normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's only highlighting. Type `:nohl` and it should vanish.

Comment: you can also remove highlighting using :noh